# Angular-Block-UI does not work in Distribution - Cannot find module 'function (angular)

Tags: angularjs, bower

*Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'function (angular) {*

I'm using [Angular Block UI](https://github.com/McNull/angular-block-ui) to display blocking overlay when user clicks save.

My code works fine in development mode but when I run the distribution version of my site there is an error coming from angular block UI.

The only difference between development and distribution is that all the javascript files are packaged up into vender.js

**The development system works:**

[image: Development]

**The distribution system fails:**

*Cannot find module 'function (angular)*

[image: Distribution]

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the underlying bower component and removed the function (angular) wrapper

This has resolved my problem, but I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

[Video of how I Resolved - Cannot Find Module function(angular) in angular-block-ui](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXU6S8eH9XE&hd=1)

[image: Comment out function(angular)]